# Chrome extension to copy data from a specific location from each tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a task where in we have specific data of an element open in a webpage and there are multiple elements data opened in multiple pages. The data I need is located at a same location in each webpage. I need to copy the entire row of that data and as sson as I flip the tab by Ctrl + tab the next data of next element should be copied too and in the end I need to export them in an excel file.

I would appreciate if someone can tell me how do I go about it.

I want this to be done as a browser extension.

Comment: Don’t forget to mark a good answer as “Solution” (✓). It gives the author +15 points and (something no one will tell you) it protects your question from being deleted.

Comment: @Anneerrudh, did my answer allow you to do what you want ? If you need help for pusher code or anything else, i can give you some sample working code ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can enable a Chrome extension allowing you to execute any Javascript of your own on any website.
For example this extension "Custom JavaScript for websites" : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija

You Copy/paste in the textarea of this extension your Javascript such as mydata = $("#element_i_want_to_copy").text(); console.log(mydata);

You can then retrieve in Chrome console the data...

If you want that the Javascript on every page send the data on a page of your own that will centralize automatically all the data sent by each Chrome tab loaded page, then you can use online (free) services like "Pusher", cf https://pusher.com/.

The Chrome extension "pushes" the data on your html page, that "receives" the message and displays it in a textarea for instance or a html  of your choice...